# How to get thumbnail of youtube video from url using php and API

Tags: php, jquery, youtube

Below code, I got title and description but I want image as well as
 how to get the main image of video from JSON data.

```
$videoid = 'cMC_PtgKDJE';
$apikey = 'xyzxyzxyz';  //My API key

$json = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='.$videoid.'&key='.$apikey.'&part=snippet');
$ytdata = json_decode($json);
print_r($ytdata);
echo '<h1>Title: ' . $ytdata->items[0]->snippet->title . '</h1>';
echo 'Description: ' . $ytdata->items[0]->snippet->description;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each YouTube video has 4 generated images.You can create the url as fallows

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<video-id-here>/0.jpg
```

**[DEMO](https://img.youtube.com/vi/2Dl-iK_Vpkc/1.jpg)**

If you want high quality image  then you can read following atricle

[how to get a youtube video’s thumbnail image in high quality](https://www.thewebtaylor.com/articles/how-to-get-a-youtube-videos-thumbnail-image-in-high-quality)

How to get video id from youtube url

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zWKm-LZWm4&feature=relate";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $url_vars );
echo $url_vars['v'];    
  // Output: 7zWKm-LZWm4
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot now  i got it one more thing i want to ask in this case i had given youtube id directly in varaible from one video  but how to  get youtube video  id  at first  using php.

Comment: actually i copied from youtube url is there any way to extract it from whole url that's what i want to ask. like  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmBm59V-SOE

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

Answer (score 1):

Each video on YouTube provides several thumbnails of different quality

Default (for small thumbnails):
`$ytdata->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->default->url;`

Medium:
`$ytdata->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->medium->url;`

High:
`$ytdata->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->high->url;`

Standard:
`$ytdata->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->standard->url;`

Maximum resolution:
`$ytdata->items[0]->snippet->thumbnails->maxres->url;`